# assigning a string to string to an array using matlab

Tags: matlab

I am having issues assigning a string to an array
for example if I have Test = [11 12]

```
for ii=1:1:endofloop
    if Test(ii) == 11
     Test(ii) = 'J';
    end
 end
```

The output of this results in [74 12], How do i make it to output [J 12] instead of [74,12] I have tried the char function but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can't have a vector with caracter. You need to use cell array: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-cell-array.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your difficulty lies in `74` being the [ascii character code](http://www.asciitable.com/) of `J`. I don't believe you can mix strings and integers in a vector. However, if J is symbolic and not needed as a string but instead is representative of a value you could do this

```
syms J; % Not a string 'J' but rather a symbolic value. An 'x' so to speak
for ii=1:1:endofloop
    if Test(ii) == 11
     Test(ii) = J;
    end
 end
```

and then later replace J for a value using [subs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) where you would do something like

```
subs(Test,J,value) % value is somewhere earlier defined
```

If however, you actually want to use a mixed array Adiel is right in recommending a cell array.

If you are just using this as a translation script, say where `J=11` and `K=12` then I would recommend using a separate datastructure to hold your translated value, for instance a simple string. Example:

```
s = '';
for ii=1:1:endofloop
    if Test(ii) == 11
     s = strcat(s,'J');
    end
    if Test(ii) == 12
     s = strcat(s,'K');
    end     
end
```